# Importing Linux-type files in zim-wiki

Tags: linux, zim

I have a folder with some text files. As not uncommon in Linux, these files have no extension, and the file names have white spaces. E.g. a text file is named `Data for project X`.

Unfortunately, if I want to import this folder into a new `zim` notebook (File -> Open Another Notebook), these files will not be added, because `zim` only takes files of the type `Data_for_project_X.txt`.

So, the question is simple. Is there any way to make zim override such settings, and actually import my files in my current format?

Answer (score 0):

One imperfect solution is to manually import pages (File -> Import Page...). To see files without the `.txt` extension, select the `All files` option in the menu.

The solution is imperfect because (i) it needs to be done file by file, and (ii) zim will actually create a new file with the required name (`Data_for_project_X.txt`). One way to override these problems is to use some script to change the name of all files (and folders), replacing spaces with `_`, and adding `.txt` extension to text files. Then, you can create a new project from the folders.

I am not aware of a solution which enables you to use zim with the Linux filenames. It would be nice to see such solution.